# Confusion Matrix with number of classified/misclassified instances on it (Python/Matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, confusion-matrix

I am plotting a confusion matrix with matplotlib with the following code:

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *

conf_arr = [[33,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3], [3,31,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,4,41,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], [0,1,0,30,0,6,0,0,0,0,1], [0,0,0,0,38,10,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,3,1,39,0,0,0,0,4], [0,2,2,0,4,1,31,0,0,0,2], [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,36,0,2,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,5,37,5,1], [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,39,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,38] ]

norm_conf = []
for i in conf_arr:
    a = 0
    tmp_arr = []
    a = sum(i,0)
    for j in i:
        tmp_arr.append(float(j)/float(a))
    norm_conf.append(tmp_arr)

plt.clf()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
res = ax.imshow(array(norm_conf), cmap=cm.jet, interpolation='nearest')
cb = fig.colorbar(res)
savefig("confmat.png", format="png")
```

But I want to the confusion matrix to show the numbers on it like this graphic (the right one). How can I plot the `conf_arr` on the graphic?

[image: confusion matrix]

Comment: wow, this code is as readable as the Phaistos Disk

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [**text**](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text) to put arbitrary text in your plot.  For example, inserting the following lines into your code will write the numbers (note the first and last lines are from your code to show you where to insert my lines):

```
res = ax.imshow(array(norm_conf), cmap=cm.jet, interpolation='nearest')
for i, cas in enumerate(conf_arr):
    for j, c in enumerate(cas):
        if c>0:
            plt.text(j-.2, i+.2, c, fontsize=14)
cb = fig.colorbar(res)
```

[image: matrix with numbers]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It exactly does what I need. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could really see of doing it was to use annotations. Try these lines:

```
for i,j in ((x,y) for x in xrange(len(conf_arr))
            for y in xrange(len(conf_arr[0]))):
    ax.annotate(str(conf_arr[i][j]),xy=(i,j))
```

before saving the figure. It adds the numbers, but I'll let you figure out how to get the sizes of the numbers how you want them.