# Scikit learn confusion matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I am making a confusion matrix with sci-kit learn with two different lists: gold_labels and predicted labels

```
cm = confusion_matrix(gold_labels, predicted_labels)
pl.matshow(cm) #I use pl to generate an image
pl.title('Confusion Matrix')
pl.ylabel('True label')
pl.xlabel('Predicted label')
pl.colorbar()
```

where gold labels/predicted labels looks something like this: (list of strings)

```
gold_labels =["hello", "apple".....] 
predicted_labels=["hi", "apple"....]
```

The confusion matrix is generated and it looks beautiful but the labels are indices (0,1,2) and I can't tell if 0 maps to "hello" or "apple"
So, I have two questions:
1) Is there a way to make the labels appear on the generated confusion matrix in pl
2) If not, how do I know what in my list of strings matches to its corresponding index

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  Can you just put label on the confusion matrix?  If so, here's an example that I answered awhile ago about how to do this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897826/confusion-matrix-with-number-of-classified-misclassified-instances-on-it-python/2901740#2901740

Comment: No, I mean that instead of the numbers showing up as labels (0,1,2,3) I want the strings (hello, apple to show up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the [plt.xticks](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) and [plt.yticks](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.yticks) functions.

First you have to choose where you want your ticks to be on the axis, and then you have to set the labels.

For example: suppose you have an `x` axis that spans from `5` to `25` and you want 3 ticks at `8`, `15` and `22`, and you want labels `foo`, `bar`, `baz`.

Then you should call:

```
# do your plotting first, for example
x = np.arange(5, 25)
y = x * x
plt.plot(x, y)
# and then the ticks
plt.xticks([8, 15, 22], ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
# And finally show the plot
plt.show()
```

In your case, since your labels ticks are at `[0, 1, 2]` and you want `hello`, `apple` and `orange` as your labels. You should do:

```
plt.xticks([0, 1, 2], ['hello', 'apple', 'orange'])
```