# Matplotlib Plot list of 16 lists

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

So I have a list of 16 lists of integers. How could I make a graph using matplotlib so that one would have a space of 15x15 completely filled with a label of the integer in that position? Am I asking too much or is there some way I could tweak the list?
Example of a list:

```
[[9, 6, 13, 14, 0, 8, 10, 2, 4, 7, 1, 3, 5, 12, 15, 11],
 [26, 30, 27, 16, 17, 24, 20, 18, 29, 23, 25, 19, 28, 31, 22, 21],
  [35, 46, 37, 41, 39, 40, 33, 36, 45, 42, 47, 43, 34, 44, 32, 38],
   [58, 56, 53, 61, 54, 63, 50, 62, 49, 55, 48, 51, 57, 59, 52, 60],
    [66, 76, 69, 75, 72, 71, 73, 68, 79, 67, 65, 64, 78, 74, 77, 70],
     [80, 91, 83, 93, 85, 90, 92, 86, 95, 81, 89, 94, 84, 87, 88, 82],
      [103, 97, 98, 104, 111, 109, 102, 108, 96, 107, 110, 106, 99, 101, 105, 100],
       [115, 122, 126, 121, 127, 113, 118, 116, 125, 119, 117, 120, 112, 123, 114, 124],
        [140, 130, 141, 132, 143, 131, 133, 137, 138, 134, 129, 135, 128, 139, 142, 136],
         [158, 147, 156, 144, 157, 152, 150, 149, 154, 159, 148, 151, 153, 155, 146, 145],
          [163, 169, 175, 166, 174, 173, 165, 160, 170, 162, 167, 171, 168, 161, 164, 172],
           [187, 188, 186, 180, 182, 184, 177, 189, 185, 181, 179, 176, 183, 178, 191, 190],
            [200, 203, 204, 195, 196, 205, 206, 197, 201, 193, 194, 207, 198, 199, 192, 202],
             [218, 220, 212, 213, 222, 219, 223, 221, 215, 216, 209, 217, 211, 214, 210, 208],
              [239, 236, 233, 230, 235, 229, 226, 238, 227, 234, 231, 225, 237, 228, 232, 224],
               [254, 247, 240, 251, 241, 245, 252, 243, 255, 248, 242, 249, 250, 246, 244, 253]]
```

How could I plot this so that it would take up a 15x15 space with the integers labeled? (Each point would be labeled with the integer it represents in the array)

Comment: What do you mean the "label"?

Comment: I want each point to be labeled with the integer it represents

Comment: Just use `text` or `annotate`, and specify the `(x,y)` position of each integer.  See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897826/confusion-matrix-with-number-of-classified-misclassified-instances-on-it-python  or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821125/how-to-plot-confusion-matrix-with-string-axis-rather-than-integer-in-python

Comment: Im not sure I understand how to apply those examples to my own list, I am very new to matplotlib & numpy

Comment: @tom10 just to alert you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [text](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text) to do this, as tom10 said. Here's an example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[9, 6, 13, 14, 0, 8, 10, 2, 4, 7, 1, 3, 5, 12, 15, 11],
[26, 30, 27, 16, 17, 24, 20, 18, 29, 23, 25, 19, 28, 31, 22, 21],
[35, 46, 37, 41, 39, 40, 33, 36, 45, 42, 47, 43, 34, 44, 32, 38],
[58, 56, 53, 61, 54, 63, 50, 62, 49, 55, 48, 51, 57, 59, 52, 60],
[66, 76, 69, 75, 72, 71, 73, 68, 79, 67, 65, 64, 78, 74, 77, 70],
[80, 91, 83, 93, 85, 90, 92, 86, 95, 81, 89, 94, 84, 87, 88, 82],
[103, 97, 98, 104, 111, 109, 102, 108, 96, 107, 110, 106, 99, 101, 105, 100], 
[115, 122, 126, 121, 127, 113, 118, 116, 125, 119, 117, 120, 112, 123, 114, 124],
[140, 130, 141, 132, 143, 131, 133, 137, 138, 134, 129, 135, 128, 139, 142, 136],
[158, 147, 156, 144, 157, 152, 150, 149, 154, 159, 148, 151, 153, 155, 146, 145],
[163, 169, 175, 166, 174, 173, 165, 160, 170, 162, 167, 171, 168, 161, 164, 172],
[187, 188, 186, 180, 182, 184, 177, 189, 185, 181, 179, 176, 183, 178, 191, 190],
[200, 203, 204, 195, 196, 205, 206, 197, 201, 193, 194, 207, 198, 199, 192, 202],
[218, 220, 212, 213, 222, 219, 223, 221, 215, 216, 209, 217, 211, 214, 210, 208],
[239, 236, 233, 230, 235, 229, 226, 238, 227, 234, 231, 225, 237, 228, 232, 224],
[254, 247, 240, 251, 241, 245, 252, 243, 255, 248, 242, 249, 250, 246, 244, 253]]

# Create a figure and axis
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)

# Plot each number based on its position
y = 1
for row in data:
    x = 1
    for n in row:
        plt.text(x,y,str(n))
        x +=1
    y += 1
# Set the x and y axes limits
xMax = len(data)
yMax = len(data[0])    
ax.set_xlim(0, xMax + 1)
ax.set_ylim(0, yMax + 1)

plt.show()
```

[image: plot of integers in a grid]

Comment: Note that instead of your nested loop, you could use `ndenumerate`, e.g. `for (x,y), n in np.ndenumerate(data): plt.text(x+1,y+1, str(n))` (or maybe with x and y swapped, I can never remember).