# Plot value in unequal list/array shape using Imshow and cmap

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, confusion-matrix

I want to plot my values to be something like this:

[image]

I have 4x12 values in a list.

```
values = [[2.78, 2.78, 2.78, 2.79, 2.79, 2.79, 2.8, 2.8, 2.81, 2.82, 2.82, 2.77], 
          [2.98, 2.98, 2.98, 2.99, 2.99, 2.99, 3.0, 3.0, 3.01, 3.02, 3.03, 2.98], 
          [3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 3.02, 3.02, 3.03, 3.04, 3.04, 3.05, 3.01], 
          [2.98, 2.98, 2.98, 2.99, 2.99, 2.99, 3.0, 3.01, 3.01, 3.02, 3.03, 2.99]]
```

I've tried to follow the confusion matrix method but it seems limited only for an equal array shape [Confusion Matrix with number of classified/misclassified instances on it (Python/Matplotlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897826/confusion-matrix-with-number-of-classified-misclassified-instances-on-it-python)

any advice?

Comment: Answered! 

I forgot to 
import from numpy import *
from pylab import *

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the code of the question that you put: [Confusion Matrix with number of classified/misclassified instances on it (Python/Matplotlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897826/confusion-matrix-with-number-of-classified-misclassified-instances-on-it-python):

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *

conf_arr = [[2.78, 2.78, 2.78, 2.79, 2.79, 2.79, 2.8, 2.8, 2.81, 2.82, 2.82, 2.77], 
          [2.98, 2.98, 2.98, 2.99, 2.99, 2.99, 3.0, 3.0, 3.01, 3.02, 3.03, 2.98], 
          [3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 3.02, 3.02, 3.03, 3.04, 3.04, 3.05, 3.01], 
          [2.98, 2.98, 2.98, 2.99, 2.99, 2.99, 3.0, 3.01, 3.01, 3.02, 3.03, 2.99]]

norm_conf = []
for i in conf_arr:
        a = 0
        tmp_arr = []
        a = sum(i,0)
        for j in i:
                tmp_arr.append(float(j)/float(a))
        norm_conf.append(tmp_arr)

plt.clf()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
#res = ax.imshow(array(norm_conf), cmap=cm.jet, interpolation='nearest')
#cb = fig.colorbar(res)

res = ax.imshow(array(norm_conf), cmap=cm.jet, interpolation='nearest')
for i, cas in enumerate(conf_arr):
    for j, c in enumerate(cas):
        if c>0:
            plt.text(j-.2, i+.2, c, fontsize=14)
cb = fig.colorbar(res)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @ibellomo thanks! stupid me I just missed to import the * module